# How to get count and Percentage using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given below is the database table(TableA).

```
SlNo  TeamName  WorkInfo 
----  -------   -------  
1     Team1        0    
2     Team1        0    
3     Team1        1     
4     Team2        1    
5     Team2        1 
6     Team2        1      
7     Team3        0      
8     Team3        1
```

I have two text boxes for selecting start and end date. I want to display details in between that dates.

Given below query is giving the details and count based on the start date and end date.

```
SELECT TeamName,Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN WorkInfo = 1 THEN SlNo end) AS Count1 , 
       Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN WorkInfo = 0 THEN SlNo end) AS Count0 FROM tableA 
WHERE (SubmitDate BETWEEN @start AND @end) GROUP BY TeamName
```

The above query shows the out put like given below:

```
TeamName   Count1   Count0
--------   -----    ------
Team1        1        2
Team2        3        0
Team3        1        1
```

I want to display the percentage based on the `greatest count` in `Count1` and `Count0` . Help me to modify the above solution. `The expecting output sample is given below:`

Here  in `Count1` 3 is the greates value.Based on that I have to find the percentage of Count1 values. And in `Count0` 2 is the greatest value.Based on that I have to find the percentage of Count0 values.

```
TeamName   Count1   Count0  Percentage1  Percentage0
--------   -----    ------  -----------  -----------
Team1        1        2        33.33%         100%
Team2        3        0        100%           0%
Team3        1        1        33.33%         50%
```

Help me to find a proper solution. Thank You.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu : Yes

Answer (score 0):

To display percent to total in SQL, we want to leverage the ideas we used for rank/running total plus subquery. Different from what we saw in the SQL Subquery section, here we want to use the subquery as part of the SELECT. Let's use an example to illustrate. Say we have the following table,

```
Name    Sales
John    10
Jennifer    15
Stella  20
Sophia  40
Greg    50
Jeff    20
```

we would type,

```
SELECT a1.Name, a1.Sales, a1.Sales/(SELECT SUM(Sales) FROM Total_Sales) Pct_To_Total 
FROM Total_Sales a1, Total_Sales a2 
WHERE a1.Sales <= a2.sales or (a1.Sales=a2.Sales and a1.Name = a2.Name) 
GROUP BY a1.Name, a1.Sales 
ORDER BY a1.Sales DESC, a1.Name DESC;
```

Result:

```
Name    Sales   Pct_To_Total
Greg    50  0.3226
Sophia  40  0.2581
Stella  20  0.1290
Jeff    20  0.1290
Jennifer    15  0.0968
John    10  0.0645
```

The subquery `SELECT SUM(Sales) FROM Total_Sales` calculates the sum. We can then divide the individual values by this sum to obtain the percent to total for each row.

Reference is [here](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-percent-to-total.html)

Answer (score 0):

Is this is what you are asking or i am totally wrong?

`exec ('SELECT TeamName,Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN WorkInfo = 1 THEN SlNo end) AS Count1 , 
       Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN WorkInfo = 0 THEN SlNo end) AS Count0,
((Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN WorkInfo = 1 THEN SlNo end)/'+ @totaldays + ')*100) as Percentage1,
((Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN WorkInfo = 0 THEN SlNo end)/' + @totaldays + ')*100) as Percentage0 FROM tableA 
WHERE (SubmitDate BETWEEN ' + @start ' + AND ' + @end + ') GROUP BY TeamName')`

Answer (score 0):

If the percentage is base on the date different of start and end date, not the data itself

```
SELECT 
  TeamName,
  Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN WorkInfo = 1 THEN SlNo end) AS Count1, 
  Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN WorkInfo = 0 THEN SlNo end) AS Count0,
  Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN WorkInfo = 1 THEN SlNo end) * 100.0 / (DATEDIFF(Day, @start, @end) + 1) AS Percentage1,
  Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN WorkInfo = 0 THEN SlNo end) * 100.0 / (DATEDIFF(Day, @start, @end) + 1) AS Percentage0
FROM 
  tableA 
WHERE 
  (SubmitDate BETWEEN @start AND @end) 
GROUP BY 
  TeamName
```

Comment: Hi eric. Your answer is working. But I , modified my question. Can you help me to find the solution.